# On which basis are Beit Knessets established and what role do they fulfill compared to the Temple

Tags: synagogue, beis-hamikdash, commentaries

With the Temple gone, the Beit Knessets/Synagogues have arrived. But on which basis (verses) are they established and which functions, tasks, goals or purposes of the original Temple do they fulfill?

Comment: `But on which basis (verses) are they established` Why does their establishment need to be based on verses. They seem like useful institutions with or without supportive verses.

Comment: In mishna Taanit we can see that there was alot of Bateknesset at time of the temple. Leynian maamadot.

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1144404/jewish/Building-a-Synagogue.htm

Comment: "the Beit Knessets/Synagogues have arrived." What makes you think there were no synagogues before the Temple was destroyed?

Comment: I think I didn't expressed myself correctly, I just wondered if a Beit Knesset was more than a house of study or comming together to pray. With the Temple gone I wondered if a Beit Knesset fulfills any tasks of the Temple. Secondly I wondered if the Beit Knessets like we know these days were established based on certain verses of the Tenach or were established based on other thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

The notion of Bate Knessiot and Bate Midrashot, house of prayer and house of study is independent. The notion of Bet Mikdash is for sacrifices and prayers, but not prior. When Bet Hamikdash was destroyed, nothing really replace it, but BK and BM became all our patrimony, and Tefila and Torah study became occupations that replace Avoda. See Rabenu Yona on the 2nd Mishna of Avot for a good explanation about Tefila replacing Avoda. Chazal also said that learning Hilchot Korbanot plays the role of Korbanot. So today, places of prayer and learning are a kind of substitute of Mikdash. But the purpose was not to create a "new kind" of house.

Comment: Think you ! Great comment